# parse file from input with papaparse

Tags: angular, highcharts, papaparse

I am trying to update a chart with a file from input. I parse the file with Papaparse.

chart.component.ts:

```
  update_chart(csvdata) {

    const jsonData = Papa.parse(csvdata);
    this.data1 = this.prepareData(jsonData.data);


    const self = this,
      chart = this.chart;

    chart.showLoading();

    setTimeout(() => {
      chart.hideLoading();

      self.chartOptions.series = [
        self.chartOptions.series[0],
        {
          data: self.data1
        }
      ];

      self.updateFromInput = true;
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

chart.component.html:

```
<div class="boxChart__container">
    <div>
        <highcharts-chart
            id="container" 
            [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
            [constructorType]="chartConstructor"
            [options]="chartOptions"
            [callbackFunction]="chartCallback"
            [(update)]=updateFromInput
            [oneToOne]="true"
            style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;">
        </highcharts-chart>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="file">Choose File</label>
            <input type="file" id="file" (change)="update_chart($event)">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, as soon as i choose my file, i get this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader':
>   parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.
>       at _global.. [as readAsText] (zone-evergreen.js:1354)
>       at c._readChunk (papaparse.min.js:7)
>       at c._nextChunk (papaparse.min.js:7)
>       at c.stream (papaparse.min.js:7)
>       at Object.parse (papaparse.min.js:7)
>       at ChartComponent.update_chart (chart.component.ts:138)
>       at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ChartComponent.html:16)
>       at handleEvent (core.js:38098)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.js:39716)
>       at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:39352)

I don't know what is meant by "is not type blob" and why this concerns my application. Does anyone have an idea what's wrong?

The CSV File:

[image]

```
Tasks,Run,Count
task1,4.96,150
task2,156.166666666667,150
task3,279.369565217391,92
task4,1718,16
task5,2.375,16
```

I can't change the csv, it has to be like this.

I reproduced the error here: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-mntjy

Comment: Internal note: author asked the same question yesterday, but he didn't like comments and suggestions, so he removed it and asked again in a new ticket. @J.Doe, please, respect others who want to help you and don't remove their answers with no reason.

Comment: I admit this was a fault! I didn't get any answers only one comment which didnt really help me... but im still sorry. I found the solution to my problem so I'll make an answer here and hope to help others!

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `csvdata` in the `update_chart` method is the event but not the reference to a file (blob). Change the parameter name and supply the file reference to `Papa.parse` as follows.

```
update_chart(event) {    
    const jsonData = Papa.parse(event.files[0]);
```

Comment: you could log the event parameter to find out about its internals

Comment: Event {isTrusted: true, type: "change", target: input#file, currentTarget: input#file, eventPhase: 2, …}

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve my problem was building a FileReader:

```
  readDocument(fileChangeEvent: Event) {
    return new Observable<Object>(obs=>{
      const file = (fileChangeEvent.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
      let fileReader = new FileReader();

      fileReader.onload = (e) => {
        obs.next(fileReader.result);
      }
      fileReader.readAsText(file);  
  })
```

and then using the file in the subscription.

```
this.readDocument(inputdata).subscribe(document=>{
```